# When were Star Wars minifigs changed to use more realistic skin tones?

Tags: minifigures, star-wars

I've looked on Bricklink and searched there, but I can't determine when LEGO changed the old model of the minifigures to the new model with more details and more realistic skin tones.

Can some one help me with this? I just need the year.

Comment: The minifigures in Star Wars sets have changed many times, becoming more detailed in every step, is there any particular change ou're looking for?

Comment: Yes i know it, but i'm looking for the skin change for example. When is not be yellow for all characters, for obtain the correct color. (sorry if sound like a racists, its not my intention)

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 Yes but it not completly solved, in the set of lego where Lando Calrissian is the first to appear in the correct skin tone, the others are yellow and not with the correct skin tone. And to referent to thi "In 2004 the LEGO minifigure assumed an even wider range of skin colours when it was decided that the figures in licensed products should resemble the original characters as closely as possible."  its maybe is 2004 when start to actualitzate all Star wars minifigures? i'm not sure about that :/

Comment: That answer tells you everything. 2003: Brown Lando. 2004: Flesh tones for all licensed products.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 the answer isn't exactly correct, i searched in Brincks Links and in 2004 still existing rebel pilots with yellow skin tone, but ty for the question reference maybe it was in the middle of 2004 or something like that... In 2005 all characters have the correct skin tone.

Comment: You're right, the transition wasn't instant. For example, in 2004 [there was a mix of yellow and fleshie figs in Star Wars](https://brickset.com/sets/theme-Star-Wars/year-2004) but that doesn't change the fact that 2004 is the year the change occurred.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 i press "it solved my question" or i put a bit inforamtion here or in the other question?

Comment: I've edited the top-voted answer on the other Q to include the info you dug up about the transition. Please feel free to upvote it if you like; this question can be closed as a duplicate, or you can delete it if you prefer.